# How to change the coordinates for an embedded OpenStreetMap in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, openstreetmap, dashboard

We are trying to embed a map into our website. This works fine for a fixed address but we want the user to be able to change the address in the backend/dashboard if they want/need to. So the backend/dashboard has a form to fill in the address and it should update the map once submitted. But the map doesn't update and when we dd the return was null.

We are using OpenStreetMap because we do not wish to pay for GoogleMaps API.

Below is our code:

```
public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required',
            'mobile' => 'required',
        ]);

        $contact->building = $request->building;
        $contact->street = $request->street;
        $contact->city = $request->city;
        $contact->postcode = $request->postcode;
        $contact->phone = $request->phone;
        $contact->mobile = $request->mobile;

        $search_url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=$contact->buiding+".str_replace(' ', '+', $contact->street).",+$contact->city";
        
        $httpOptions = [
            "http" => [
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => "User-Agent: Nominatim-Test"
            ]
        ];
        
        $streamContext = stream_context_create($httpOptions);
        $json = file_get_contents($search_url, false, $streamContext);
        
        $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
        $lat = $decoded[0]["lat"];
        $lng = $decoded[0]["lon"];

        $contact->longitude = $lng;
        $contact->latitude = $lat;

        $contact->save();
        return redirect()->route('contact.index')->with("message", "Successfully updated.");
    }
```

Comment: I suggest deleting the extra comments to make the code clearer

Comment: Extra comments removed

Comment: What means: "Nothing changes." ?

Comment: The dd return was null and the map doesn't update on the frontend